# PDO/Prepared Statement Result Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code which i'm trying to obtain a single row of data into an array. I'm unsure if i'm mixing prepared statements and PDO.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_stmt as array in...
```

The Code:

```
// Prepare a select statement
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM pupils WHERE pupil_id = ?";

 if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
     // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
     $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_pupil_id);
     // Set parameters

     $param_pupil_id = $_POST['pupil_num'];
   // Attempt to execute the prepared statement

     if($stmt->execute()){

      $stmt->store_result(); 

         if($stmt->num_rows == 1){   

           $stmt->bind_result($id, $pupil_id, $name, $eal, $pp);
//Updated code
           echo $stmt->fetch()->$name;

         } else{
             echo "error";
         }
     } else{
         echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is this PDO or MYSQLI ? ;)

Comment: it says mysqli in the code

Comment: access it like an object, not an array. $stmt is an object, so use `->`, not `[]`

Comment: So it's a prepared statement in MYSQLi?

Comment: I was hinting that you mention PDO, tagged the post as PDO, but you are using mysqli. Also you already did `bind_result`, so you need `echo $name;` ... NOT `echo $stmt['name'];` and definitely not `echo $stmt->name;` or `$stmt->fetch()->$name` ... as a side, you should select each column specifically, as doing `SELECT *` can be ambiguous and mess up in `bind_result`

Comment: doing just $name results in an empty string

Comment: `if ($stmt->fetch()) echo $name;`

Comment: apologies i had removed the fetch, thats sorted it.